# What is ChunkParserI in nltk.chunk ? What exactly it has been called for?

Tags: nlp, nltk, parsing

```
from nltk.chunk import ChunkParserI 
from nltk.chunk.util import conlltags2tree 
from nltk.corpus import gazetteers 

class LocationChunker(ChunkParserI): 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.locations = set(gazetteers.words()) 
        self.lookahead = 0
        for loc in self.locations: 
            nwords = loc.count(' ') 
        if nwords > self.lookahead: 
            self.lookahead = nwords
```

What is ChunkParserI  in nltk.chunk ? What exactly it has been called for?
Also, please explain the code.
What is the difference between chunking and parsing?

Answer (score 1):

Parsing is the process of decomposing a string into it's constituent symbols (if the string is a word or a sequence of characters) or syntactic components (if the string is a meaningful textual entity like a short story, a scientific abstract or a sentence). In an NLP context, when one talks about parsing, he/she usually refers to the latter interpretation.

Chunking (in an NLP context) is a specific form of parsing in that it extracts groups of words in so-called 'chunks'. These groups of words or chunks  are 'meaningful short phrases from the sentence (tagged with Part-of-Speech). Chunks are thus made up of words and the kinds of words are defined using the part-of-speech tags. One can even define a pattern or words that can't be a part of chunk and such words are known as 'chinks''[1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nlp-chunking-and-chinking-with-regex/). The latter can be defined with chunking rules.

I assume the code you posted comes from "Natural Language Processing: Python and NLTK" by Hardeniya et al.[2](https://leonmercanti.com/books/machine-learning/Natural%20Language%20Processing%20%20Python%20and%20NLTK%20(2016).pdf)? From there i can find that the LocationChunker class 'starts by constructing a set of all locations in the gazetteers corpus. Then, it finds the maximum number of words in a single location string so it knows how many words it must look ahead when parsing a tagged sentence.' (cf. Chapter 5, p. 319)

Comment: Thanks @Joshua1990. I am fine with the difference. this was not my source. But I am still not clear about code.